# Modify preview targets and save them

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I'm using the following Event hook :

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Entry::EVENT_REGISTER_PREVIEW_TARGETS, function ($event) { }
```

The `$event` variable contains an array with the current `$previewTargets` as well as the entry that fired the event

I would like to modify the `$previewTargets` and then save them to the entry they belong to.

If I simply modify the `$previewTargets` the changes are lost at the end of the request

How can I save those changes ?